# 「ありがとう」というコメントは禁止？

Tags: 討議, コメント

スタックオーバーフローのヘルプセンターの[「質問にあたって」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)には以下のような記載があります。

> 「ありがとう」というために自分の質問や回答にコメントをつけないでください。

しかし、個人的には「ありがとう」とコメントされて悪い気はしませんし、StackExchangeのメタでもこれに関しては[議論](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101124/official-reference-for-dont-leave-thank-you-comments)されていて、**「「ありがとうは全面禁止」ではなく「コメント欄をありがとうであふれさせないでください」」** 的な解釈も出来るかなと思っています。

ということで、日本語版スタックオーバーフローでは、以下のような方向性はどうかと思っていますが如何でしょうか？ご意見募集します。

1. 質問者として　　 :　回答に機械的に「ありがとう」を付けるのは避ける
2. 第３者として　　 :　「ありがとう」の代わりにプラス票を入れる
3. モデレータとして :　単なる「ありがとう」というコメントでもスパム的でなければ削除しない

なお、「ありがとう、動きました」というコメントは、その回答で合っているという情報にもなるので、多少は役に立つコメントだと考えています。

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> 「ありがとうは全面禁止」ではなく「コメント欄をありがとうであふれさせないでください」

上記解釈がベターと考えます。

システム的には [賛成投票(upvote)](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) や [回答の承認(accept)](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) があるとはいえ、謝意の表明まで一律NGではあまりに“冷たい”と思います。その一方で大量の「ありがとう」コメントが溢れても誰も得をしないので、明確な線引きは難しいでしょうね。

---

> 質問者として　　 :　回答に機械的に「ありがとう」を付けるのは避ける

質問者としては、有用な回答が付くのは非常にうれしいことですから、**賛成投票(upvote)や回答の承認(accept)を行ったうえで**、さらに直接的に感謝を伝えたいのであれば、たいして情報量のない「ありがとう」コメントでも許容されると思います。（質問者は一人しか居ませんから、コメントがあふれる心配も無用です。）

> 第３者として　　 :　「ありがとう」の代わりにプラス票を入れる

第三者としては、**賛成投票(upvote)がベスト**だと思います。質問者なら+5／回答者なら+10 信用度が増加しますから、単なる「ありがとう」コメントよりも“実利的”な謝意表明です。

賛成投票の[権限(信用度15以上)](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)を持っていない場合は、…心の中で感謝するにとどめておいてください。

「ありがとう」や「+1」に加えて、コメントで**新しい追加情報を提供する**なら許容されるというのが線引きラインでしょうか？

> モデレータとして :　単なる「ありがとう」というコメントでもスパム的でなければ削除しない

本家StackOverflowでたまに見かける「thank youやme tooであふれそうだから保護」を適用すれば良いのではと思います（日本語版でも使える？）。冗長なありがとうコメント削除に関しては、保護適用後の削除が無難と思いました。

Comment: 質問の保護は（本来0repから行える）回答で「ありがとう」されるのを止めるものなので、コメントには使えないかと… http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/new-protected-question-status/

Comment: @unarist ありがとうございます。てっきりコメント追加も保護されるのかと思っていました。でもまあ、そういう保護対象であると示すことはできますね。

Comment: @yohjp 回答で「ありがとう」のパターンは、通報があれば適時コメントに変換するようにしています。一方、コメントでの「ありがとう」に関しては、確かに明確な線引きが難しいので、当面は通報に任せる（通報が３件を超えると自動的に削除されるようなので）という形でどうかなと思っています。

Answer (score 9):

あくまで予測ですが。。。

「ありがとうございます」のコメントをOKにすると、「ありがとうございます」のコメントで質問者がcloseしたつもりになり、ベストアンサー無しで放置される質問が増えちゃいそうな気がします。

Comment: 確かにその可能性は否定できませんね。ただ、現状ベストアンサー無しで放置されているのは、ベストアンサーを選ぶという事自体を理解されていないケースかなとも思っています。ということで、ベストアンサーを忘れていると思われる物に関しては、できるだけコメントでフォローして行きたいとは思っています。

Comment: あと、ベストアンサーにすると同時にありがとうとコメントしている物を削除するのまでダメというのはさすがに厳しすぎるかなとも思っています。