# 回答のお礼のコメントは不要なんですか？

Tags: 討議

質問に回答がついたので、お礼コメントしようとしたら
コメントの注意事項に
”追加情報や改善依頼は書いていいけど「+1」や「ありがとう」は避けましょう”
という趣旨が記載されていて
お礼コメント書くのを躊躇してしまいます。

質問サイトは善意でなりたっているので
「回答ついたら、お礼コメントする」のが
マナーだとおもっていたのですが
このサイトではそういう儀礼的で議論が進まないものは不要という
雰囲気なのでしょうか？

Comment: 関連：[ありがとう-というコメントは禁止？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1693)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

基本的に**質問者が**「ありがとう」と記載しても問題はないかと思います。

ただし、質問者以外の人が「ありがとう。私も動きました。」と記載した場合、
そのコメントが呼び水となり、他の人もお礼を記載して言ってしまうと
その場合にはコメント欄がありがとうで埋まってしまうので良くないという考えです。

その代わりとして、役に立ったという意味合いでUpvote(+1)や回答の承認があります。
Upvoteや回答の承認を行えば基本的に回答者に役に立った旨が伝わるので結果的にお礼となります。

……とここまでが関連リンクにも似たようなことが書いてあり、サイトの意向だと思います。

---

私の個人的なものとしてはコメント欄でお礼を貰うことは
「解決して感謝している旨」が分かるのでうれしいものではあります。
動作が上手く行った、解決した旨を伝えたい、と言った時にお礼コメントを送るのはいいのではないでしょうか？

ただし、コメントだけで終わらず必ず回答の承認まで行ってください。
回答の承認を行うことでシステム的に解決した質問と判断され、
他の同様の問題を抱えている人に対しての解決策にもなります。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました。過度にならない程度に「ありがとう」コメントするとともに、解決した場合は承認も行うように致します。